# Python pass class instance to its method (function) decorators

Tags: python, class, methods, decorator, self

I want to do the following:
I've got a class, and that class has a dict named *cmds*. I want to dynamically add elements to it via decorators. The decorator should be a function, a method of this class.
Example code on what I want:

```python
class Foo(object):
    #In a class:
    @cmd("exit")
    def cmd_exit(self, *args):
        self.run=0
        print("Exiting mainloop...")
    @cmd('reconnect')
    def cmd_reconnect(self):
        self.connect(self._host)
```

For that to work, **I need to pass self to the method `cmd`, which is a decorator**. However, `cmd` does not receive `self`.
So how can I do this?
**EDIT:**
My `Foo.cmd` method has the following definition:

```python
def cmd(self, name):
    def decorator(funcs):
       fname=name if name else funcs.__name__
          self.cmds[fname]=funcs
          self.cmdLogger.info("Registrated function %s", name)
          return
    return decorator
```

and it only receive the string I pass to the decorator(e.g "exit" and 'reconnect')
Note that the inner decorator(called *decorator*) returns `None`, so the original function the decorator was called on is "removed".

Comment: Assuming your first code block is intended to be nested inside of a `class Foo:` block (you should add that!): Not only does `self` not exist yet, the class itself does not exist yet.  At the top level of the `class` block, you're still in the process of defining what that class is supposed to contain.  So of course you can't have an instance of that class.

Comment: @Kevin ... oh @Đ#đ, that was the problem. I can't call a method on a method when it's being defined. But I can do it later, by moving the `cmd_` functions outside of the class, and calling `Foo.cmd(name)` on them. I must be really tired that I overlooked it. You should write an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inherit 'cmds' from another class, to keep track of your logs in 'central place':

```
from functools import wraps

def cmd(*name):
    def wrapper(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def real_decorator(*args, **kw):
            fname = name[0] if name else fn.__name__

            cls = args[0]
            cls.cmds[fname]=fn
            #self.cmdLogger.info("Registrated function %s", name)
            return fn(*args,**kw)
        return real_decorator
    return wrapper

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cmds = {}
        #self.cmdLogger = ...

class Foo(Logger):
    @cmd("exit")
    def cmd_exit(self, *args):
        self.run=0
        print("Exiting mainloop...")

    @cmd('reconnect')
    def cmd_reconnect(self):
        self.connect(self._host)

f = Foo()
f.cmd_exit()
print(f.cmds)
```

Returns:

```
Exiting mainloop...
{'exit': <function Foo.cmd_exit at 0x7fb11cfee048>}
```